# Crear página con listado de todos los archivos que hay en una carpeta

Tags: php, web, archivo, descarga

soy muy novato y posiblemente esta sea una pregunta bastante tonta, pero desde hace tiempo quiero hacer una cosa y no sé si es posible o si ya existe algo para eso.
Lo que quiero es poder meter una serie de archivos de fotos, videos o zips a una carpeta y que automáticamente se cree una página web donde pueda entrar y ver un listado de esos archivos y me de la opción de descargarlos. No quiero algo tipo una base de datos donde tenga que meter los registros o un panel de control tipo cms o wordpress. Quiero algo simple; meto o quito archivos de una carpeta de mi servidor y la página se actualiza automáticamente. Además tendría que crear automáticamente los distintos directorios y carpetas dentro de cada uno. ¿es esto posible, cómo tendría que hacerlo?. Mi servidor soporta php.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Lo mejor sería crear un solo PHP que procese todos los archivos de una carpeta con `scandir` y luego listar todos los archivos en base a parámetros que se pueden pasar por la URL

Answer (score 0):

Pues si lo que buscas es usar o crear un programa que te permita gestionar los archivos que tienes en un servidor yo usaría programas ya existentes tales como [FileZilla Client](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?platform=win64) o similares.

Si lo que buscas es una página web donde poder hacer todo eso para a posteriori añadirle otras funcionalidades, que sea como una página de administración podrías usar [CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/) por ejemplo y ahí cocinarte tu propia aplicación en php siguiendo las directrices que comentan en el [manual oficial de PHP para ello](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php).

Espero haber aclarado un poco tus dudas. Si tienes más puedes preguntarme :).

Un saludo

Comment: Las preguntas que no proveen ningún intento de resolución por parte de quien preguntó, son consideradas de baja calidad y eventualmente terminan cerradas, por favor evita contestarlas

Comment: Ahm, pensaba que también se podían preguntar dudas independientemente del nivel, me pareció que sí quería resolverlo, pero en el futuro pues evitaré contestarlas :)